# PowerBI, Azure AD and keycloak authentication. Using keycloak as Idps to log into Power BI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, keycloak, azure-ad-b2b

I am not an [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure) expert and I am starting to get familiar with [Azure AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure_Active_Directory), so this question is also to clarify some questions I have.

My objective in stories:

- The user logs in keycloak
- The user gets on a web application
- The user clicks on the Power BI application link
- The user get redirected to Power BI (which having already a keycloak session, grants the user the access directly)
- The user is authenticated as an Azure AD user and can use Power BI

I am looking for a way to authenticate the access to Power BI using keycloak. Apparently Power BI only supports Azure AD as authentication, and therefore I started investigating on how to log in into Azure AD using keycloak:

*[Federation with SAML/WS-Fed identity providers for guest users (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation)*

I have found this Microsoft documentation that I suppose is the documentation to implement any [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) provider with Azure AD, so here are my questions:

How can I redirect a user to keycloak and then keycloak redirects to Azure? (Usually I configure the target application to use Keycloak as idps and so I got a link or a prefix that uses keycloak as that idps.)

Is possible to redirect directly to a Power BI application using this approach?

Comment: AFAIK it is possible to use keycloak with azure ad as idp but not the reverse way .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use keycloak with azure active directory as identity provider but the reverse way may not be possible  as keycloak doesn’t has the ability to forward the sign in token request received for the application configured back to Azure AD for authorization.

If you have any ideas or suggestions ,you can provide your feedback or idea or suggestion  [https://feedback.azure.com](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/22920db1-ad25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789)

Comment: Hello, I am trying now to federate keycloak with Azure using External Identity providers and than auto accelerate the home realm discovery, do you know if there are issues with that aswell?